# Can all correlated sub queries be queried using joins in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, correlated-subquery

So say I have a table

`Dress(Dress_id, Colour, Value)` and another table

`On_Loan(Dress_id, Start_date, End_date)`

and I have this query, which I am not sure it is a correlated sub query or not

`SELECT D.COLOUR,D.VALUE FROM DRESS WHERE D.DRESS_ID = (SELECT ON_LOAN.DRESS_ID FROM ON_LOAN WHERE ON_LOAN.DRESS_ID = D.DRESS_ID);`

Basically I want to return the colour and values of the dresses that are on loan. I have also queried it like this:

`SELECT COLOUR,VALUE FROM DRESS INNER JOIN ON ON_LOAN WHERE DRESS.DRESS_ID = ON_LOAN.DRESS_ID);`

Both of which give the same output, so i am wondering if all correlated subqueries can be turned into equivalent queries with joins?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS The answer is yes. Did you ask the right question?

Comment: @philipxy I dont understand what you are saying..

Comment: A JOIN and a co-related sub-query return two different results. You can't always rewrite one to the other

Comment: What's the first thing you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many correlated subqueries can be represented as `JOIN`s.  In fact, correlated subqueries are a type of join in the general sense.

But if you are asking if a "simple" `JOIN` operator query is always available, the answer is "no".  A pretty simple example is:

```
select t.*,
       (select tt.x
        from tt
        where tt.y = t.y
        order by tt.z
        limit 1
       ) as z
from t;
```

Of course, this *can* be expressed without using a correlated subquery.  But it requires more than a single `JOIN` operation.

Comment: Thats great thanks. Just wondering is my first query a correlated query?

Comment: @Drakus . . . Yes, your first query is a correlated query.  It has a correlated clause that connects the subquery to an outer query.